# ListView перестал кликаться

Tags: java, android, listview

Дело в том что, после каких то изменений в коде (откатить не получится) перестал кликаться ListView. Вообще никак не реагирует на клик. 
Попробовал всякие

```
listView.setClickable(true);
listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

безрезультатно! Попробовал создать новый фрагмент с новым ListView и тот же адаптер. Опять же клик не работает.Может что-то блокирует клики, подскажите. 2 дня мучаюсь...

**Вот фрагмент, где определяется ListView:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

public static List<VacancyModel> vacancyModelList;
SQLHelper sqlHelper;
ArrayList<Integer> watchedVacanciesList;
public static List<VacancyModel> safeVacancyModelList;
int openedVacancyID;
public static int page = 1;
public static boolean fromSplash = true;
ListView listView;
MainVacancyAdapter adapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvMainFragment);
    listView.setClickable(true);
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);

    sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(getContext());
    watchedVacanciesList = sqlHelper.haveWatchedVacancies();

    if (fromSplash) {
        safeVacancyModelList = vacancyModelList;
        //Creating an adapter and setting it to the list
        adapter = new MainVacancyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.main_row_layout, vacancyModelList);
    } else {
        //Creating an adapter and setting it to the list
        adapter = new MainVacancyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.main_row_layout, safeVacancyModelList);
    }

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(lvMainOnItemClickListener);

    return rootView;
}

public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener lvMainOnItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        MainBodyFragment fragment = new MainBodyFragment();

        VacancyModel model;
        //getting data from operating memory and transmitting it through intent
        if (vacancyModelList != null) {
            model = vacancyModelList.get(position);
            openedVacancyID = vacancyModelList.get(position).getId();
        } else {
            model = safeVacancyModelList.get(position);
            openedVacancyID = safeVacancyModelList.get(position).getId();
        }
        sqlHelper.saveWatchedVacancy(openedVacancyID);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(VacancyModel.class.getCanonicalName(), model);
        bundle.putInt(MainBodyFragment.MAIN_VACANCY_POSITION, position);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_switch, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
};
```

**Адапртер:**

```
    public class MainVacancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private List<VacancyModel> vacancyModelList;
    private List<Integer> favVacanciesIDList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<Boolean> isSelected;
    SQLHelper sqlHelper;
    ArrayList<Integer> watchedVacanciesList;
    public static int selectCount;

    public MainVacancyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<VacancyModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vacancyModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(getContext());
        favVacanciesIDList = sqlHelper.getFavVacanciesID();
        watchedVacanciesList = sqlHelper.haveWatchedVacancies();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    //Finding textViews and inserting data into them
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);

            holder.tvProfession = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvProfession);
            holder.tvProfileName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvProfileName);
            holder.tvSalary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSalary);
            holder.tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostCr);
            holder.cbxFav = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbxFav);
            holder.vacancyViewed = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.viewedLayoutMain);
            holder.logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivVacSource);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
holder.tvProfession.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getProfession());
        holder.tvProfileName.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getProfile());
        holder.tvSalary.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getSalary());
        holder.tvDate.setText(vacancyModelList.get(position).getDate());

        try {
            //checking if there the same record exists in favourite table and tagging the star

            //checking if there is a vacancy that have been viewed
            for (int j = 0; j < watchedVacanciesList.size(); j++) {
                int recordID = vacancyModelList.get(position).getId();
                int watchedRecordID = watchedVacanciesList.get(j);
                if (recordID == watchedRecordID) {
                    holder.vacancyViewed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    holder.vacancyViewed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //setting listener for changing the icon. Inserting determined rows in db and deleting it
        holder.cbxFav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                int getPosition = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag().toString());
                int rowID = vacancyModelList.get(position).getId();

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvProfession;
        private TextView tvProfileName;
        private TextView tvSalary;
        private TextView tvDate;
        private CheckBox cbxFav;
        private LinearLayout vacancyViewed;
        private ImageView logo;
    }
    }
```

**main_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvMainFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
            android:listSelector="@color/transparent"
            android:padding="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**main_row.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:background="@drawable/card_bg"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <com.isakovch.Utils.Fonts.BoldFont
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:id="@+id/tvProfession"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvPostCr"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tvPostCr"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <com.isakovch.Utils.Fonts.LightFont
        android:id="@+id/tvPostCr"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="post created"
        android:textColor="#767676"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_name" />

    <com.isakovch.Utils.Fonts.LightFont
        android:id="@+id/tvProfileName"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Company"
        android:textColor="#767676"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivVacSource"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_hh_kg"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <com.isakovch.Utils.Fonts.LightFont
        android:id="@+id/tvSalary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Salary"
        android:textColor="#767676"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:id="@+id/cbxFav"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
        android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox_transparent" />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/salary"
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_salary"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/viewedLayoutMain"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_status_watched" />

    <com.isakovch.aukg.Utils.Fonts.LightFont
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="@string/status_watched"
        android:textColor="#767676"
        android:textSize="11dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: покажите ещё разметку итемов адаптера, есть подозрение что клик перехватывает holder.cbxFav.setOnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: Обновил........

Comment: Вы были правы. Все комментарии с checkbox убрал заработало. Но еще вопрос, как он перехватывает?

Comment: посмотрите как он отрисовывается в макете - вероятно что занимает всё пространство поверх остальных вьюх.

Comment: Странно, но нет он маленький. Обратно закомментировал коды. И кликнул по checkbox он работает, а row не кликается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внешний слушатель нажатий конфлиткует со всем, что кликабельно в разметке. Единственное решение  никогда не пользовать внешние слушатели и назначать их только изнутри адаптера, т.е. только в методе `getView()`

---

И переходить на `RecyclerView`, у которого нет внешних слушателей нажатий и такой проблемы возникнуть не может в принципе.